# Changing a Knockout Computed function after definition

Tags: knockout.js

I have a situation where I am building a base class in typescript and part of the class defines an error computed observable:

```
public hasError: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
```

In the constructor for the class, I define it with a simple function that always returns false:

`this.hasError = ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => { return false});`

The intention is that the user of this class will define whatever function makes sense to define if this class has an error or not. This has worked fine because generally the hasError variable has been redefined before it was used and the using code would be referencing the newly redefined computed.

However, I am  now adding functionality to the base class that will have another computed set based on some other state in the class and the state of hasError. it will be defined as:

`this.success = ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => {
    return !this.hasError() && this.complete();
});`

the problem is that this.success is now bound to the simple definition of hasError that always returns false because it is getting bound to it before the using code has a chance to redefine hasError.

Is there a way with a computed to just redefine its function? I am assuming that if I could redefine the function for hasError, and send a message saying that hasError has mutated, then the definition of success would continue to function properly because it is linked to the instance of the computed, not to the function that was originally used to define the computed.

I am using knockout v3.4.something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hasError computed is itself wrapped in an observable, then your secondary computed will be notified of changes to the function. You'll have to adjust the usage to unwrap the function first, but that could probably be abstracted behind a property getter/setter if needed.

```
class TestBase {
    public success: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    public complete: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    public hasError: KnockoutObservable<KnockoutComputed<boolean>>;    

    constructor() {
        this.hasError = ko.observable(ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => { return false; }));
        this.success = ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => {
            var hasError = this.hasError();
            return !hasError() && this.complete();
        });
    }
}

class Test extends TestBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.hasError(ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => { return true; }));
    }
}
```

Edit: If you don't want the external usage to change here's how you would use a property get/set to wrap it. Rename the internal observable to something else (_hasError in this case), and make hasError a Property to pass the underlying observable's value:

```
class TestBase {
    public success: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    public complete: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    public _hasError: KnockoutObservable<KnockoutComputed<boolean>>;

    public get hasError() {
        return this._hasError();
    }
    public set hasError(func: KnockoutComputed<boolean>) {
        this._hasError(func);
    }

    constructor() {
        this._hasError = ko.observable(ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => { return false; }));
        this.success = ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => {
            var hasError = this._hasError();
            return !hasError() && this.complete();
        });
    }
}

class Test extends TestBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.hasError = ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => { return true; });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, that is close to what I ended up with (see my edits to my answer). stacking the hasError like that is interesting. I will have to see how that works in my binding because I am using the hasError in the html through a binding. I suspect that the binding needs to be: hasError() rather than just hasError.

Comment: @GregVeres Like I mentioned you can wrap it in a property if you don't want the binding or other usages to have to change. (See edit)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a direct answer to the question, but it dawned on me how to change the problem so that I can find a solution.

Instead of trying to change the original function the computed is bound to, I am now storing a function pointer in the class and having the computed's function call that function instead. My solution becomes:

```
class MyClass{
    public hasError: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    private errorFn: KnockoutObservable<() => boolean>;

    constructor() {
        this.errorFn = ko.observable<() => boolean>(null);
        this.hasError = ko.computed<boolean>((): boolean => {
            if (this.errorFn() != null) {
                return this.errorFn()();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    public setErrorFunction(fn: () => boolean): void {
        this.errorFn(fn);
    }
}
```

Now I can redefine what constitutes an error by passing in a different function in the setError method. I had to make the errorFn an observable to get the computed to evaluate properly and to pick up other dependencies that might be in the new errorFn. I was hoping that just calling this.hasError() would force a re-evaluation and create a new dependency graph but it doesn't appear that is the case.